# How can I release the lock permanently if a condition is true inside the locked code section?

Tags: c#, .net, locking, thread-synchronization

I have the following code with me, where I need to produce some Wrapper Objects. And once I produce enough Objects, I need to release the lock, as if the statement `lock(lockObject)` was never present inside the code.

```
lock (lockObject)
{
    if (wrappersProduced < myQ.BoundedCapacity)
    {
        try
        {
            WordApplicationWrapper w = new WordApplicationWrapper();
            myQ.Add(w);
            wrappersProduced++;
            Logger.DebugMemory("Wrappers Produced - " + wrappersProduced.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger.DebugMemory("Couldn't add Wrapper - " + e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Can this be done?

Comment: You can conditionally lock checking a boolean

Comment: `lock(lockObject)` is the same as: `Monitor.Enter(lockObject)` and `Monitor.Exit(lockObject)`.

Comment: Never ask for a thread race bug as a feature.  Use BlockingCollection.TryAdd().

Comment: How can I put conditional lock on a boolean if that boolean itself needs to be synchronized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in comments it is just a matter of locking only when something is true. You can add a helper class to use it in using statements.

```
public class LockHelper : IDisposable
{
    private bool needLock;
    private bool lockTaken;
    private readonly object padLock = new object();
    public LockHelper(bool needLock)
    {
        this.needLock = needLock;

        if (needLock)
            Monitor.Enter(padLock, ref  lockTaken);
    }

    public void Exit()
    {
       if (lockTaken)
       {
            Monitor.Exit(padLock);
            lockTaken = false;
       }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (lockTaken)
            Monitor.Exit(padLock);
    }
}
```

Then use it as

```
//Will lock only when the condition is true
using (var myLock = new LockHelper(some condition))
{

    if (wrappersProduced < myQ.BoundedCapacity)
    {
        try
        {
            WordApplicationWrapper w = new WordApplicationWrapper();
            myQ.Add(w);
            wrappersProduced++;

            //exit
            if (wrappersProduced == 100)
                myLock.Exit();

            Logger.DebugMemory("Wrappers Produced - " + wrappersProduced.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger.DebugMemory("Couldn't add Wrapper - " + e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think  there is  no  added value with your solution apart  the Dispose pattern

Comment: @K.B What else do you think the question is all about? As I understand op is asking how to conditionally lock. My answer addresses it.

Comment: the  OP  says  "I need to release the lock, as if the statement lock(lockObject) was never present inside the code."  so he need to release conditionally which can not happen AFAK  when you enter your critical section

Comment: @K.B You could release conditionally but when lock is taken and not released will prevent all other threads from taking the lock. I believe op doesn't want that. Let's wait for OP's reply.

Comment: I adjusted your code so that it works with his use case.

Comment: by  doing this    if (wrappersProduced == 100)
                myLock.Exit();  or  while(wrappersProduced<100){  WordApplicationWrapper w = new WordApplicationWrapper();
            myQ.Add(w);
            wrappersProduced++; }   is not the some ??  why you should add all this overhead and reinventing the wheel

Comment: The code locks on 'some condition' where as my condition needs to be WrapperProduced==100 only. Using this code, I need a lock on 'some condition' itself because it will be accessed by many threads at once.

Comment: And if I try to make 'some condition' synchronized, then I am back at my original question again.

Comment: What I actually need is, when you do `myLock.Exit();`, that should be the end, nobody after that should be able to acquire the lock again as if the lock was never present.